# Why cant I type in the text box of the second form

Tags: html, css, forms, input

Im trying to make two froms on one page. one right underneather the other. The first form is to put the main information in and then the second form is suppossed to be a report. The problem is that the second form wont allow any text to be put into the text box, it doesnt even seem to regonise that there is a text box on the page.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#tl {
   padding: 1em;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 1400px;
  height:190px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
}

#tl input {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}


#report {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 1400px;
  height:690px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#report input {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}


.fdate{
  position:relative;
  left:60px;
  top:30px;
}

.fsales{
  position:relative;
  left:320px;
  bottom:22px;
}

.fservice{
  position:relative;
  left:650px;
  bottom:75px;
}

.fpart{
  position:relative;
  left:1000px;
  bottom:127px;
}

.fqty{
  position:relative;
  left:20px;
  bottom:120px;
}


.fhour{
  position:relative;
  left:376px;
  bottom:175px;
}


.fcust{
  position:relative;
  left:691px;
  bottom:225px;
}


.fname{
  position:relative;
  left:1068px;
  bottom:280px;
}

  .inputs{
   position:relative;
   top: 20px;
    
  }
.title1{
  position:relative;
  bottom:430px;
  left:500px;
}
```

```html
<!--form for top level info--> 
<div id = "tl">
<form>
  
  <div class = "inputs">
  
   <div class="fdate">
        <label for="fdate">Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fdate" name="fdate"><br><br>
      </div>
  
  
  <div class="fsales">
        <label for="fsales">Sales Order:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fsales" name="fsales"><br><br>
      </div>
  
  
  <div class="fservice">
        <label for="fservice">Service Order:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fservice" name="fservice"><br><br>
      </div>
  
  <div class="fpart">
        <label for="fpart">Part Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fpart" name="fpart"><br><br>
      </div>
  
  <div class="fqty">
        <label for="fqty">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fqty" name="fqty"><br><br>
      </div>
  
  <div class="fhour">
        <label for="fhour">Hours:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fhour" name="fhour"><br><br>
      </div>

      <div class="fcust">
        <label for="fcust">Customer:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fcust" name="fcust"><br><br>
      </div>

      <div class="fname">
        <label for="fname">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
      </div>
  </div>
 
 <div class = "title1">
   <div> Missing & Damaged Report</div>
  </div>
</form>
 </div>


<!--second form for missing parts--> 

<div id = "report">
<form>
  
   <div class="P1">
        <label for="P1">Part Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="P1" name="P1"><br><br>
      </div>
</form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `postion:relative;` to `input` class see work example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#tl {
   padding: 1em;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 1400px;
  height:190px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
}

#tl input {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}


#report {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 1400px;
  height:690px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#report input {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}


.fdate{
  position:relative;
  left:60px;
  top:30px;
}

.fsales{
  position:relative;
  left:320px;
  bottom:22px;
}

.fservice{
  position:relative;
  left:650px;
  bottom:75px;
}

.fpart{
  position:relative;
  left:1000px;
  bottom:127px;
}

.fqty{
  position:relative;
  left:20px;
  bottom:120px;
}


.fhour{
  position:relative;
  left:376px;
  bottom:175px;
}


.fcust{
  position:relative;
  left:691px;
  bottom:225px;
}


.fname{
  position:relative;
  left:1068px;
  bottom:280px;
}

  .inputs{

   top: 20px;
    
  }
.title1{
  position:relative;
  bottom:430px;
  left:500px;
}
```

```html
<!--form for top level info--> 
<div id = "tl">
<form>
  
  <div class = "inputs">
  
   <div class="fdate">
        <label for="fdate">Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fdate" name="fdate"><br><br>
      </div>
  
  
  <div class="fsales">
        <label for="fsales">Sales Order:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fsales" name="fsales"><br><br>
      </div>
  
  
  <div class="fservice">
        <label for="fservice">Service Order:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fservice" name="fservice"><br><br>
      </div>
  
  <div class="fpart">
        <label for="fpart">Part Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fpart" name="fpart"><br><br>
      </div>
  
  <div class="fqty">
        <label for="fqty">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fqty" name="fqty"><br><br>
      </div>
  
  <div class="fhour">
        <label for="fhour">Hours:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fhour" name="fhour"><br><br>
      </div>

      <div class="fcust">
        <label for="fcust">Customer:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fcust" name="fcust"><br><br>
      </div>

      <div class="fname">
        <label for="fname">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
      </div>
  </div>
 
 <div class = "title1">
   <div> Missing & Damaged Report</div>
  </div>
</form>
 </div>


<!--second form for missing parts--> 

<div id = "report">
<form>
  
   <div class="P1">
        <label for="P1">Part Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="P1" name="P1"><br><br>
      </div>
</form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks its working now - Just so I can learn a bit more about it, why does having possition relative effect this?

Comment: because the `div` with class `inputs` is above the second `form`, so when you click on the `textbox` you are actually clicking on the first `div`